# change li class in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there any way to add/remove a class to an HTML li tag from C# codebehind?  for example, here's my code.

```
<li>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlClipboardEbulletin" runat="server">
    <a href="/eBulletin.aspx"><asp:Label ID="lblClipboardEbulletin" runat="server" /></a>
    </asp:Panel>
 </li> 
 <li class="noborder">
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlClipboard" runat="server">
     <a href="/displayMyList.aspx"><img src="../Images/Clipboard.jpg" alt="Clipboard" /></a>
     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkClipboard" Text="Clipboard" NavigateUrl="~/displayMyList.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
     </asp:Panel>
 </li>
```

in the codebehind, I have to toggle the visibility of pnlClipboard based on other data.  If pnlClipboard = false, I want to set the class of the first li to class="noborder"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give your li tag the `runat="server"` attribute and an id.

```
<li runat="server" id="myli">
```

Now in your code behind you can use it like any control

```
myli.Attributes["class"] = "myClass";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add runat="server" and ID attribute to first

and you will be able to access it from codebehind

markup:

```
<li runat="server" id="firstItem">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlClipboardEbulletin" runat="server">
```

codebehind:

```
firstItem.Attributes["class"] = "noborder";
```